# Eclipse Java Error: Cannot find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, compiler-errors, program-entry-point

I am using *Eclipse Luna* and i am trying to run a simple text program but Eclipse gives the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

I have no idea what's going on. I haven't found anything useful on Stack Overflow or Google. Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This is a String");

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: select your main class for the project from run configurations.

Comment: Is your file named `Main.java` and is the class named `Main`? And is your `main` method defined as `public static void main( String[] args)`?

Comment: yes all of that is done

Comment: How about editing your question, copying and pasting your file. Please follow formatting rules, though: select the entire code block and click on the `{}` button to format it as code.

Comment: And one more thing: did you define it in `Run configurations` as `Main` or as `Main__`?

Comment: We need your code spinet to understand your issue? If you think that your code is correct then clean it compile it.... select main class then right click then run....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looking fine !

Do following steps to run your class

1. Select your project, go to `Project` section in menu bar then click `clean`.
2. In tool section click on `Build Automatically`.
3. Select your `class` right click on it and then select `run`.

Comment: that doesn't work: there is no tool section are you sure you're using Eclipse Luna?

Comment: that doesn't work: there is no tool section are you sure you're using Eclipse Luna? Oops sorry for the duplicate :)

Comment: I am telling about menu bar, edited answer. have you followed provided steps, which issue you are facing now?

Comment: i don't understand i have clicked Project then Clean and i see a window with to radio buttons: Clean all projects and Clean all projects selected below. Underneath the radio buttons there is a list of all my projects in my workspace. Below that there are also buttons that say "OK" and "Cancel".

Comment: You can clean all your projects or your particular project, and after that select `Build Automatically`

Comment: oh im sorry i understand now.

Comment: Does build automatically need to be on before I click it?

Comment: No need after cleaning your project you can select it make sure that right sign is there i.e. this option is on. It will help you to compile your project each time when you save it

Answer (score 0):

In the menu *Run*, select *Run Configurations...*.

In the dialog box that opens, on the left side, you are supposed to have an entry *Java Application*, and under it, there should be your class (and maybe other classes you worked on before). It may be named `Main` or `Main__` here.

Select it. If it was erroneously named `Main__`, change that to `Main` in the *Name:* field.

Now look at the entry for *Main Class*. In the text field, it should say `Main`. If it says `Main__` or anything else, change that to `Main`.

*Apply* and *Run*.